# Image Application in WPF and Perfomance

Tags: wpf, image, image-processing

I am planning to build Image processing application using WPF. Brightness /Contrast and Histogram are main operation of this application. I have downloaded the application " Foundations: Bitmaps and Pixel Bits" from
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534995.aspx
. But when I tried to open the images which are more than 1200x1600, It is very slow. How to increase the performance. Is any one worked on Image processing in WPF.

Please suggest me how to solve this perfomance issue in WPF for image(more than 1600x1200) operation.

Thanks you,
Harsha

Comment: The performance is probably due to what the article is trying to accomplish, and not because of WPF issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week searching the net I got some useful information. People are using COM DLLs for all the Image related calucualtions and update the WPF application. Here is the link to MSDN:Custom BitmapEffect Sample - RGBFilter

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771475(VS.90).aspx

Buut Problem with this is, one have register the COM dll.

But I have also found the sample code where registration of COM Dll is not required. 
http://johnmelville.spaces.live.com/cns!79D76793F7B6D5AD!115.entry

I have Opened the Image of size 3000x3500 and changed the RGB values. It is very smooth.

But I didn't understand how slider in the XMAL interact with this COM DLL and How to write this COM DLL.

If any one who understand the this code please explain. It will be very helpful for all.

Thanks and regards
Harsha